# C# How to Change the Button properties by selecting a Button via a variable

Tags: c#, winforms, button

i want to change the Text properties of a Button not by directly select them. 
Like:

```
Button1.Text = "New Text"
```

Instead i want to do something more like this?:

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
   Button.id[i].Text = str[i];
}
```

I'm new to C# and windows applications so maybe someone can help me with this Problem.

Comment: Please specify if this is WinForms or WPF.

Comment: you have serval buttons and you want to change their text in a loop?

Comment: Regardless of Framework: Have you heard of the term "Property Binding" before?

Comment: It is WinForms. I'm new to this so i didn't heard about "Property Binding" i will look for that and see were it gets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create a name from `i`, lets say `Button{i}`, and then find the button using `FindControl()` and do the assignment:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    string btnName = $"Button{i}";  //eg. Button1, Button2, Button3 ...
    Button myBTN = FindControl(btnName) as Button;
    myBTN.Text = str[i];
}
```

Alternatively in winform applications you can use the ControlCollection.Find() insead of FindControl():

```
Button myBTN = this.Controls.Find(btnName, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
```

Comment: FindControl is for server controlls

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    string[] str = { "New Text 1", "New Text 2", "New Text3", "New Text 4", "New Text 5" };
    Button[] button = { button1, button2, button3, button4, button5 };

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                button[i].Text = str[i];
            }
```